# How to generate an example POJO from Swagger ApiModelProperty annotations?

Tags: java, json, swagger

We are creating a REST API which is documented using Swagger's `@ApiModelProperty` annotations. I am writing end-to-end tests for the API, and I need to generate the JSON body for some of the requests. Assume I need to post the following JSON to an endpoint:

```
{ "name": "dan", "age": "33" }
```

So far I created a separate class containing all the necessary properties and which can be serialized to JSON using Jackson:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPostRequest {
  private String name;
  private String age;
  // getters and fluid setters omitted...
  public static MyPostRequest getExample() {
    return new MyPostRequest().setName("dan").setAge("33");
  }
}
```

However, we noticed that we already have a very similar class in the codebase which defines the model that the API accepts. In this model class, the example values for each property are already defined in `@ApiModelProperty`:

```
@ApiModel(value = "MyAPIModel")
public class MyAPIModel extends AbstractModel {

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "dan")
  private String name;

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "33")
  private String age;

}
```

Is there a simple way to generate an instance of MyAPIModel filled with the example values for each property? Note: I need to be able to modify single properties in my end-to-end test before converting to JSON in order to test different edge cases. Therefore it is not sufficient to generate the example JSON directly.

Essentially, can I write a static method getExample() on MyAPIModel (or even better on the base class AbstractModel) which returns an example instance of MyAPIModel as specified in the Swagger annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible as of the time of this answer. The closest possibilities I found are:

1. `io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters`: The method `read()` creates `Model` objects, but the `example` member in those models is null. The examples are present in the `properties` member in String form (taken directly from the APIModelParameter annotations).
2. `io.swagger.codegen.examples.ExampleGenerator`: The method `resolveModelToExample()` takes the output from `ModelConverters.read()`, and generates a Map representing the object with its properties (while also parsing non-string properties such as nested models). This method is used for serializing to JSON. Unfortunately, `resolveModelToExample()` is private. If it were publicly accessible, code to generate a model default for an annotated Swagger API model class might look like this:

```
protected <T extends AbstractModel> T getModelExample(Class<T> clazz) {
    // Get the swagger model instance including properties list with examples
    Map<String,Model> models = ModelConverters.getInstance().read(clazz);
    // Parse non-string example values into proper objects, and compile a map of properties representing an example object
    ExampleGenerator eg = new ExampleGenerator(models);
    Object resolved = eg.resolveModelToExample(clazz.getSimpleName(), null, new HashSet<String>());
    if (!(resolved instanceof Map<?,?>)) {
        // Model is not an instance of io.swagger.models.ModelImpl, and therefore no example can be resolved
        return null;
    }
    T result = clazz.newInstance();
    BeanUtils.populate(result, (Map<?,?>) resolved);
    return result;
}
```

3. Since in our case all we need are String, boolean and int properties, there is at least the possibility to parse the annotations ourselves in a crazy hackish manner:

```
protected <T extends MyModelBaseClass> T getModelExample(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        T result = clazz.newInstance();
        for(Field field  : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ApiModelProperty.class)) {
                String exampleValue = field.getAnnotation(ApiModelProperty.class).example();
                if (exampleValue != null) {
                    boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    setField(result, field, exampleValue);
                    field.setAccessible(accessible);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create model example", e);
    }
}

private <T extends MyModelBaseClass> void setField(T model, Field field, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    LOGGER.info(type.toString());
    if (String.class.equals(type)) {
        field.set(model, value);
    } else if (Boolean.TYPE.equals(type) || Boolean.class.equals(type)) {
        field.set(model, Boolean.parseBoolean(value));
    } else if (Integer.TYPE.equals(type) || Integer.class.equals(type)) {
        field.set(model, Integer.parseInt(value));
    }
}
```

I might open an Issue / PR on Github later to propose adding functionality to Swagger. I am very surprised that nobody else has seemed to request this feature, given that our use case of sending exemplary model instances to the API as a test should be common.